# Angular .htaccess rewrite rules without changing the url

Tags: angular, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am running an Angular app in multiple locales; en/nl/fr.
Everything works ok if you visit the app through www.domain.com/fr/

But I want user to visit www.domain.com without redirect them to /fr/. So redirect them without changing to url. How is that possible from the root folder? Eventually I want to redirect them based upon a cookie var or browser language.

The apps have there own htaccess so that angular handles the route when you refresh a page.

```
root
- /fr/
- /en/
- /nl/
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: BTW. The base-href paths of the apps are of course /nl/ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and error, we fixed it. If you are interested, pm me :)